# why linux set the data-segment to __USER_DS at the prologue of exception handler

Tags: linux, data-segment, exceptionhandler

I'm trying to read Linux source code(2.6.11)

In the exception handler, at entry.s,
error_code:

```
movl $(__USER_DS), %ecx
movl %ecx, %ds
movl %ecx, %es
```

I don't know why loading user data segment here. Since it is supposed to be entering the exception handler code which runs in the kernel mode, the selector is supposed to be __KERNEL_DS.

I checked other versions of the code, they do the same thing specifically too at this place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the exception handler is entered with `ds` and `es` already set to the data segment, it makes no difference except for maybe a microsecond of delay.  Exception handlers don't usually need to be fast.

But what might cause going to the exception handler?  Could it have been because a bad value was loaded into a segment register and then referenced?  In such cases it is important for the code to establish a safe environment.  `cs` is set by the exception invocation.  To be bulletproof, `ss` and `esp` should be set up too.

---

Followup:

Looking at the 2-6.22.18 kernel for i386, I don't see exactly that:

```
error_code:   /* the function address is in %fs's slot on the stack */
     pushl  %es
     ...  pushes %ds, %eax, %ebp, %edi, %esi, %edx, %ecx, %ebx, %fs
     ...  along with pseudo-ops to manage stack frame layout
     movl  $(__KERNEL_PERCPU), %ecx
     movl  %ecx, %fs
     popl  %ecx   // retrieves saved %fs
     ... sets up registers for the exception function
```

The symbol `__KERNEL_PERCPU` is a macro defined (in `include/asm-i386/segment.h`) as `0` for non-SMP machines and `(GDT_ENTRY_PERCPU * 8)` for SMPs.  The 8 is for the GDT entry size (I think) and the `GDT_ENTRY_PERCPU` relates to the entries in the per-CPU GDT.  Its value is `<base> + 15` which the comments indicate is "default user DS", so it is, in fact, the same thing.

The kernel data segment is accessed through `fs` and `ss`.  Much kernel data access is on the stack.  By keeping the user mode descriptors accessed through `ds`, very little loading of segment registers is needed.

Comment: sorry, my question is too vague. What I mean is why it loads the __USER_DS rather than __KERNEL_DS. I have modified the original question.

Comment: @Holmes:  I have amended my answer.  Does that explain it better?

Comment: @walllyk: Guess I make clear of what does "...very little loading of segment register" means finally. Thx again!

Comment: Can you please explain "The kernel data segment is accessed through fs and ss". Doe it means kernel exception can not use DS?

Comment: @dimba:  The exception *can* use `DS`: the entry code sets it up.  However, DS is mapped to user space, presumably for inspecting/altering user mode stack and variables.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't fully get it. AFAIK exception is a legal C code that runs in kernel-space. Compiler can generate assembly that uses DS, so exception can access kernel data. But we set DS to __USER_DS instead of __KERNEL_DS. I'm confused :)

Answer (score 1):

In the entry.s:

```
#define RESTORE_ALL
    RESTORE_REGS
    addl $4, %esp;
1:  iret;
.section .fixup,"ax";
2:  sti;
    movl $(__USER_DS), %edx;
    movl %edx, %ds;
    movl %edx, %es;
    movl $11,%eax;
    call do_exit;
.previous;
.section __ex_table,"a";
    .align 4;
    .long 1b,2b;
.previous
```

This macro will be called at the end of exception/interrupt/syscalls. The fix code set ds&es to USER_DS, which shows that iret  itself will raise an exception once the ds&es's DPL is not 3(user privilege).

So linux set ds&es to USER_DS at the very beginning of exception/interrupt/syscalls to avoid this exception.